# Python Requests Connection Error

Tags: python, python-requests

So when I have this code it work perfect:

```
import requests
import re

def clean(toclean):
    m = re.findall("'(.*?)\'", str(toclean))
    rdy = ''.join([item.rstrip('\n') for item in m])
    return pretty(rdy)

def pretty(pret):
    m = re.findall('UA-[0-9]+-[0-9]+', str(pret))
    rdy = ''.join([item.rstrip('\n') for item in m])
    return rdy

r = requests.get('http://editinginsider.com')

m = re.findall('UA-[0-9]+-[0-9]+', r.text)

print clean(m)
```

But when I try to iterate over a list in a text file line by line I get this name or services not know error

```
import requests
import re

def clean(toclean):
    m = re.findall("'(.*?)\'", str(toclean))
    rdy = ''.join([item.rstrip('\n') for item in m])
    return pretty(rdy)

def pretty(pret):
    m = re.findall('UA-[0-9]+-[0-9]+', str(pret))
    rdy = ''.join([item.rstrip('\n') for item in m])
    return rdy

f = open( "domains.txt", "r" )

for line in f:
    r = requests.get(line, timeout=7)
    m = re.findall('UA-[0-9]+-[0-9]+', r.text)
    print clean(m)

f.close()
```

So what is the deal? I have tried sleeping, timeouts, upping the max connection attempts and it fails.

My bet is something dumb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused most likely caused by a '\n' character at the end of the line from the domain.txt file.  The following might work:

```
r = requests.get(line.strip(), timeout=7)
```